# Python Scrape CRSF token

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I would like to scrape the _AntiCsrfToken value here:

how would I do this I have tried a few things but I always get an empty array when using b4s could someone help me I'm sure its a simple few lines :)

```
<form method="post" class="newsletter-form  js-newsletter-form" action="/en/customer/subscribablesignup" data-success-message="Thank&#32;you&#32;for&#32;signing&#32;up!">
    <input type="hidden" name="_AntiCsrfToken" value="bccfe8ae52e74d85bb26851bed7ebbbb">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input name="redirectUrl" type="hidden" value="/">

    <p id="newsletter-desc-footer" class="newsletter-form__desc">
        Sign up for email updates and promotions.
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.form.input.attrs['value'])
```